# Why can I not use the jQuery variable?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand how to use the variable  `this_table` in the piece of code below that appends data to a table. The variable `this_table` looks like this #myTable1. Jquery does not see it as a variable in the append section of the code.
`$('#myTable > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>');` works fine.

The jQuery

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function(e) {

    var tableid = $(this).closest("div").find("table").attr("id"); //find table id
    var this_table = '#' + tableid; //Add ID selector
    $('this_table > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>'); //Append to table

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is interpreted as a string. You need to concatenate the variable with the string...

Change this line:

```
    $('this_table > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>'); //Append to table
```

To this:

```
    $(this_table + ' > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>'); //Append to table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery find function. change the line

```
    $('this_table > tbody > tr').append('<td>info,</td>'); //Append to table
```

to this:

```
    $(this_table).find("tr").append("<td>info</td>");
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily select the exact same element. He uses the ">" selector, which means direct child. Your code would select all siblings that are a tr element. You would actually use $(this_table).children('tbody').children('tr').append('<td>info,</td>') to get the same selector he is currently using...